# MPMoviePlayerController not playing any video content [due to ARC and memory management]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to get a video playing in an iOS applocation, using MPMoviePlayerController to append a movie-view to an existing view when a user pushes a button.
The view appears as a black box on the right position and everything, but nothing happens.
I am expecting the movie to start playing, but nothing happens and no hints from the application on why.

Can anyone see where this goes wrong?

```
-(IBAction) playButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_mpeg4" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSLog(@"Using videoPath %@", path);
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 220);
   [player play];
```

}

The movie exists and logs the correct path, but still no movie playing.

```
2012-07-06 11:51:13.492 experiments[84702:12203] Using videoPath /Users/marius/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/9799C851-8D2B-4CFE-8CFA-A4C4C954787F/experiments.app/sample_mpeg4.mp4
```

From what I have read and understood this should be working.
Any hints or suggestions on what to try?

---

I moved the movie to a HTTP-server (fg.mp4) and are tailing the access-logs.
When clicking the play-button the usual black window appears.
Serverside i find two new entries in the log:

```
168.122.x.x - - [06/Jul/2012:22:42:33 +0200] "GET /fg.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 304 192 "-" "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.9B176 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 5_1 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
168.122.x.x - - [06/Jul/2012:22:42:33 +0200] "GET /fg.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 33304 "-" "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.9B176 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 5_1 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
```

So the phone gets parts of the movie content, and -apparently- prepares to get the rest when needed.
Is there some obvious parameter for the MPMoviePlayerController I'm missing?

---

**UPDATE: Solution and working code**

The problem is caused by ARC and the fact that no reference to the `MPMoviePlayerController` were kept after calling the method setting up the controller.
The solution: Adding a class-variable to the class and use this to keep a reference to the controller for the lifetime of the movie.

So early in the class declaration (outside any message/function-definitions):

```
MPMoviePlayerController* mpController;
```

And the abeformentioned `playButtonClicked` uses this variable to keep track of the controller:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_mpeg4" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
mpController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
mpController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 220);
[self.view addSubview:mpController.view];
[mpController play];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As with my answer to [MPMoviePlayerController playback terminates before video finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367245/mpmovieplayercontroller-playback-terminates-before-video-finishes), this looks to be a memory management (instance lifetime) issue. Assuming you are compiling with ARC, the `player` variable is released when your `playButtonClicked:` method returns. At that point the `MPMoviePlayerController` instance takes its bat and ball, and goes home.

Try assigning the `MPMoviePlayerController` instance to a strong instance variable or property.

Comment: This was it. Thanks for putting this out here. I will update my question with the new code for future referencing if anyone else runs into this same issue

Comment: i sat on it for 2 hours... thank you! i created a strong property and now it works

Answer (score 1):

Nothing seems obviously out of place to me.  Here are some debugging tips to help narrow down the problem:

- try using a URL to an mp4 file served over http---that should tell you whether it's a UI problem or an asset problem.
- try inspecting the `url` for properties such as the file length and confirm that it exactly matches what you expect.

Comment: So by moving the file to my dev-server and accessing it from here I can see that the file get accessed (twice actually) when the view loads. Still no indications of it actually wanting to play.  

I have tried several different files, including files I know have played on the iPhone before. Stil no luck.

Comment: Then it sounds like a UI problem.  Does it work if you inject the MPMoviePlayerController's view directly on viewDidLoad (as opposed to waiting for the click)?

Comment: I am about to leave for a few hours, but will definetly check into that when I'm back.