# ARC makes playing video failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When ARC is on,I can't play video(the video is loading forever).When ARC is off,I can play video successfully.I don't know why and how to edit my code to play video with ARC on.Here is my code

```
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"big-buck-bunny-clip" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayerController];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];
}
- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayerController];
    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: You need to keep a reference to your MPMoviePlayerController or it will be deallocated at the end of "playMovie"

Comment: See borrrden's comment and use the search function... This question has been asked and answered multiple time here on SO. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365791/mpmovieplayercontroller-not-playing-any-video-content-due-to-arc-and-memory-man

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

1. Move the MPMoviePlayerController into your view delegate instead of a local variable. (This is the best way,)
2. Use `CFRetain()` to manually retain it (this CoreFoundation function will do its job on Objective-C objects without triggering ARC error. Remember to retrive it as soon as it has done its job and `CFRelease()` it.)
3. Go to project settings and mark this file with compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc`. (This will make your code leak memory like hell.)