# MPMediaPlayer always crashes

Tags: ios, mpmediaplayercontroller

I try to add a video to Viewcontroller but always fails : some one can help?

```
-(id) init 
{ 
    // always call "super" init // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value 
     if(self=[super init]) 
     {
    //play // [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:viewController.view];
     NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
     NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath]; 
     MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
     [viewController.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view]; 
     moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
     moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone; 
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieDone:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController]; [moviePlayerController play];
     //play
    }
    return self;
 }
```

Comment: Can you add more info ? Where it is crashing ? What the crash log says ? Did you checked the filePath is nil or not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPMoviePlayerController not playing any video content \[due to ARC and memory management\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365791/mpmovieplayercontroller-not-playing-any-video-content-due-to-arc-and-memory-man)

Comment: @Xena Steward - Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

In ViewController.h

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;
```

In ViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"try" ofType:@"mp4"];
        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
        moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
        [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320,300)];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
        moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
        moviePlayerController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
        [moviePlayerController play];
    }
```